# Why the variable is greater than all possible values inside the loop?

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){};
console.log(i) // 5
```

My understanding is the output in the console should be `0,1,2,3,4` or `undefined`.
How I became=5?

Comment: `i` is outside of the loop and therefore you'll only get the last value of `i` i.e. `5`

Comment: yes the last value of i should be 4, i=0 to i<5

Comment: No, for the value `4` loop has run since 4 < 5, when the value became `5` loop got terminated.

Comment: You're doing nothing 5 times (`{}`) and then logging the value that broke the loop (`5`)

Comment: i've answered you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i=0`, compare `i<5`, `true`, `for loop` is running. , `i++`

`i=1`, compare `i<5`, `true`, `for loop` is running. , `i++`

`i=2`, compare `i<5`, `true`, `for loop` is running. , `i++`

`i=3`, compare `i<5`, `true`, `for loop` is running. , `i++`

`i=4`, compare `i<5`, `true`, `for loop` is running. , `i++`

`i=5`, compare `i<5`, `false`, `for loop` stoped.

Comment: What's the sense in repeating my answer?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, every time, it increment `i` of 1, till the `i < 5` statement return `false` ^^

```js
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
console.log(i) 
};
console.log(i) // 5
```

To explain it better:

((0 + 1) < 5) == true //execute code inside brackets

((1 + 1) < 5) == true //execute code inside brackets

((2 + 1) < 5) == true //execute code inside brackets

((3 + 1) < 5) == true //execute code inside brackets

((4 + 1) < 5) == false //go out of for

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the variable outside the for loop, so, when you create it, its equal to 0, then, it iterates through the for, with values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. When it gets to 5, the iterate condition is false so it breaks the loop, and prints the value of `i`, which is 5.

If you want it to print 0 through 4, you need this code:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sixth    5  false 5  //Does not run loop nor increment, i value stays at 5
Fifth    4  true  5  //Does run loop and increment
Fourth   3  true  4  //Does run loop and increment
Third    2  true  3  //Does run loop and increment
Second   1  true  2  //Does run loop and increment
First    0  true  1  //Does run loop and increment
         |   |    |
         |   |    |
         |   |    |
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){};
```

Comment: What's the sense in repeating my answer?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, there's only one answer for this question :/ I just wrote it in a simple way he could understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of any `var` is function scope. That is the reason why this is happening.

You have to use `let`, so that it is block scoped. Then you will see `undefined` as the output.

Most coders are used to block scoped variables, which is the standard in Java, etc. That is also one of the reasons why most coders find these behaviours hard to understand in Javascript.

In order to understand why the output is '5' in this case, you need to understand that the Javascript interpreter performs "hoisting" internally. This means that it declares all `var`s in a function internally at the beginning of that same function. In your case it declares the variable before the `for` loop. Hence the variable is seen out of the for loop.

If you run this code, then you will see the "right" behaviour:

```
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){};
console.log(i)
```

This will print:

```
undefined
```

For more explanations how `var` and `let` really work, check out this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8SHaDQdul0).